# what is causing "AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'diff'"

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I am new to numpy and I am NOT understanding the documentation as regards diff. the code below throws the error. I am baffled any help would be appreciated.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/home/dave/Desktop/mcmtest/testhv calc.py", line 11, in <module>
     r =  np.log(close_prices).diff()
 AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'diff'
```

here is the test code.

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import sqrt,mean,log,diff
import pandas as pd


close_prices = [178.97,175.5,171.07,171.85,172.43,172.99,167.37,164.34,162.71,\
                    156.41,155.15,159.54,163.03,156.49,160.5,167.78,167.43,166.97,167.96,171.51,171.11]

print (close_prices)

r =  np.log(close_prices).diff()
print(r)
```

Comment: Diff is a numpy function, not an array method.

Comment: Do `np.diff(np.log(close_prices))` instead of `np.log(close_prices).diff()`

Comment: @MadPhysicist    OUTSTANDING! sorry to have been so slow on the uptake on this one. I wouldn't have spotted that at all.

Comment: I've posted an answer for you to accept in that case

Comment: @MadPhysicist thanks and I lack the reputation to score the answer so this will have to server :-) have an excellent one and thanks for taking the time. I should have spotted that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given that [`numpy.ndarray`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html) is the Python type of "numpy arrays", the error is just saying that arrays don't have a `diff` method. [`diff`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html) is a function defined in the `numpy` module.

Instead of `np.log(close_prices).diff()`, do

```
np.diff(np.log(close_prices))
```